# Dependency modifications doesn't reflect in app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to Elixir/Phoenix. I am trying to fix https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence/issues/315 issue. So I have added `coherence` in `mix.exs` as `path`. After I making changes in `coherence` it is not reflecting immediately in Phoenix app. How to fix this issue?

Comment: By “immediately” you mean without the application restart?

Comment: Yes. After making changes I also recompiled changes using `mix compile`. Still, it didn't reflect.

Comment: I am lost. Did you restart _your_ application? If yes, the changes should have been taking place. Please also show your `mix.exs` file.

Comment: Yes, I restarted my app after making changes to dependency. Here is `mix.exs` file https://gist.github.com/sivagollapalli/b297440cb80d50d269e38c778699f9f9

Comment: That’s strange; it should have been reloaded and the changes should be reflected.

Comment: Did you follow whole installation process carefully? Did you run `mix deps.get` after stopping your phoenix application?

Answer (score 0):

Hack-trick that worked for me for live-reload in Phoenix application (cold restart worked for me without any explicit workarounds): in `config/dev.exs` add the path to your external application explicitly into watched paths (`live_reload` key under `config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint`):

```rb
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  live_reload: [
    patterns: [
      ~r{../coherence/lib/.*(ex)$}, # THIS

      ~r{priv/static/.*(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$},
      ~r{priv/gettext/.*(po)$},
      ~r{lib/ammotion_web/views/.*(ex)$},
      ~r{lib/ammotion_web/templates/.*(eex)$}
    ]
  ]
```